# how make call log app in android

Tags: android, calllog

I'm a newbie programmer android I want to make an android app to record phone activities such as incoming calls, outgoing calls, or miss call and record the logs to a file .txt

what should I do ?
please help me ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [CallLog.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html)

---

Here are some good tutorials on using call log:

[android-tutorial-call-logs](http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/25-android-tutorial-call-logs)

[Call Log in Android Application](http://www.android-app-market.com/call-log-content-provider-in-android-application.html)

[reading-call-log-from-phone](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-reading-call-log-from-phone.html)

[accessing-call-logs](http://malsandroid.blogspot.com/2010/06/accessing-call-logs.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use the PhoneStateListener:

- [Android Developer: Telephony-PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)

You can read more in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a service that periodically records call logs. I'd recommend using the CallLog class and since you're a newbie, some tutorial on creating services (use Google)